# I can't get a child actor to receive messages

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to akka and I'm wondering how to get a child actor to receive messages.

I have one parent actor which prints out that it received a message and then sends a message to its child which then prints out that it received a message.

When I run the program, only the parent actor prints its message. Is there
something I'm missing?

**The parent actor**

```
class TestDirector(name: String) extends Actor {
  import TestDirector._

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

  private var child: ActorRef = _

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    println(name + " pre-start")
    child = context.actorOf(props("test-file"), name = "child-actor")
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case TestDirectory(dir) =>
      println("Test Director")
      child ! TestWorker.TestFile
  }

}

object TestDirector {
  case class TestDirectory(dirName: String)
  case class TestResponse(message: String)

  def props(dirName: String) = Props(classOf[TestDirector], dirName)

}
```

**The child actor**

```
class TestWorker(fileName: String) extends Actor {
  import TestWorker._

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case TestFile => println("Hello world")
  }

}

object TestWorker {
  case object TestFile

  def props(fileName: String) = Props(classOf[TestWorker], fileName)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TestDirector.preStart, you say

```
    child = context.actorOf(props("test-file"), name = "child-actor")
```

Those "props" are Test**Director**.props, which you imported a few lines above, so you're endlessly creating new TestDirectors. I think what you want instead is Test**Worker**.props:

```
    child = context.actorOf(TestWorker.props("test-file"), name = "child-actor")
```